# pulling data from twitter with twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to be able to pull twitter data so that I can modify and display the data. I don't want to simply display the whole feed.
I got the Oauth codes from the Twitter Developer site and got a request uri as well. But how do I make use of this? I have never really done something like this before. I don't really see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Oauth you get from the twitter developer site is the key you must use in order to request data from Twitter. You must do server side scripting, like for example PHP in order to use the new Twitter API.

Here are tutorials that you can follow if you want to retrieve the twitter feeds via json format.

- To have an idea how to use the Oauth you got from Twitter Developer site:
  **[Authenticating Twitter feed Timeline](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/)**
- Parse the json data using jquery: [LINK](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/)
- [Demo](http://www.webdevdoor.com/demos/jquery-twitter-feed/)

I can guarantee you that the tutorials are working because I have already tried it on my projects. If you have some questions feel free to comment. Thanks